# Setteing and getting Slider values

Tags: ios, objective-c, uislider

I declare slider action like this

```
         [self.slider addTarget:self.delegate action:@selector(sliderChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Now, In delegate, I want to get value changed.

```
- (void)sliderChanged:(id)sender
{
UIView *senderView = [sender view]; 
NSLog(@"Slider Changed: %f", slider.value);
```

I can not get it

Comment: `sender` is the `UISlider`.

Comment: edit with `UISlider *slider = (UISlider *)sender;`

Comment: Or just do `NSLog(@"Slider Changed: %f", [sender value]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
- (void)sliderChanged:(UISlider *)sender
{

NSLog(@"Slider Changed: %f", sender.value);
}
```